# Citing book chapter for a Springer journal using BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, apa-style

A Springer Journal requires the authors to cite a Book Chapter in exactly the following way:

> O’Neil, J. M., & Egan, J. (1992). Men’s and women’s gender role
> journeys: Metaphor for healing, transition, and transformation. In B.
> R. Wainrib (Ed.), *Gender issues across the life cycle* (pp. 107–123).
> New York: Springer.

To comply with other citation style requirements, I'm using **apalike** bibliographystyle. However, when I use the *@incollection* type in BibTeX I get the following output:

> O’Neil, J. M., and Egan, J. (1992). Men’s and women’s gender role
> journeys: Metaphor for healing, transition, and transformation. In
> Wainrib, B. R., editors, *Gender issues across the life cycle*, pages
> 107–123. New York: Springer.

Thus, instead of `Wainrib, B. R.` I get `B. R. Wainrib`; instead of  `(Ed.),` I get `, editors,` and instead of  `(pp. 107-123).` I get `, pages 107-123.`

What do I need to do to obtain the correct citation style? Is there maybe some helpful trick to make it work?

I tried other styles (chicago, apacite, apa, plainnat, spbasic), without success.

My BibTeX code:

```
@incollection{ONeil1992,
author="O'Neil, J. M. and Egan, J.",
title="Men's and women's gender role journeys: Metaphor for healing, transition, and transformation",
editor="Wainrib, B. R.",
booktitle="Gender issues across the life cycle",
year="1992",
publisher="New York: Springer",
pages="107--123"
}
```

Comment: Springer has their own biblography style defined like `spbasic`. Use that. And try with `@inbook` instead of `@incollection`.

Comment: @nidhin.- The recommendation to use the entry type `@inbook` instead of `@incollection` for the entry at hand is questionable. The former entry type is designed for pieces where the book's author(s) and the chapter author(s) are the same. That's not the case in the OP's setup.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both, `spbasic` and `@inbook` but the output is very different from what it should be. Strangely, there are many other issues with `spbasic`, also for `@article` and `@inproceedings`; `apalike` came so far the closest to the journal citation style requirements.

Comment: Which journal is it, does it not have its own bst style file?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles across the same problem, here is how you can modify **apalike.bst** (available [here](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/apalike.bst)) to obtain the required citation style (also, between the authors' names `and` is replaced by `&`):

1. Paste the following function below `FUNCTION {format.names}{ ... }`:

```
FUNCTION {format.editor.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f. }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " \& " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

2. In `FUNCTION {format.editors}` replace the line `{ editor format.names` with `{ editor format.editor.names`
3. In the same function replace `{ ", editors" * }` with `{ " (Eds.)" * }` and `{ ", editor" * }` with `{ " (Ed.)" * }`
4. In `FUNCTION {format.pages}` replace `{ "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }` with `{ "(pp. " pages n.dashify *  ")" * tie.or.space.connect }` and `{ "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }` with `{ "(p. " pages *  ")" * tie.or.space.connect }`
5. In `FUNCTION {format.names}` replace `{ " and " * t * }` with `{ " \& " * t * }`
6. Finally, in `FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}` remove the comma from `{ ", " * format.pages * }`